# Set padding of UserControl with assigned ControlTemplate?

Tags: c#, wpf, controltemplate

I recently created an `UserControl` for my `WrapPanel` to visualize some data.
I applied a `Padding` to it in order to get some space between each element.

The first version looked like this:

```
<UserControl x:Class="IFCS.EntityOverviewPanel"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:l="clr-namespace:IFCS"
         mc:Ignorable="d"
         Padding="5, 5, 5, 5"
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <!-- Code -->
</UserControl>
```

Now I just applied a `ControlTemplate` to it which overrides my `Padding` setting.

The current version looks like this:

```
<UserControl x:Class="IFCS.EntityOverviewPanel"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:l="clr-namespace:IFCS"
         mc:Ignorable="d"
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <UserControl.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="UserControl">
            <!-- Code -->
        </ControlTemplate>
    </UserControl.Template>
</UserControl>
```

I would like to apply `Padding` to my `UserControl` again but everything I tried didn't work.
I tried to apply a `Style` using

```
<UserControl.Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type UserControl}">
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5, 5, 5, 5"/>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Style>
```

but this didn't work.
Setting the `Padding` in the "header" isn't working too.

Where do I have to set the `Padding` value in order to achieve the same result as in the first version?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<UserControl Padding="5,5,5,5">
    <UserControl.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="UserControl">
            <ContentPresenter Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" />
            <!-- Code -->
        </ControlTemplate>
    </UserControl.Template>

    <!-- Content -->
</UserControl>
```